# React: Update Child Component Without Rerendering Parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What follows is a simple example:

```js
const { Component } = React
const { render } = ReactDOM

const Label = ({ text }) => (
  <p>{text}</p>
)

const Clock = ({ date }) => (
  <div>{date.toLocaleTimeString()}</div>
)

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      date: new Date()
    }
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = setInterval(
      () => this.setState({ date: new Date() }),
      1000
    )
  }
  
  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval)
  }
  
  updateTime() {
    
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Label text="The current time is:" />
        <Clock date={this.state.date} />
      </div>
    )
  }
  
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

`this.setState({ date: new Date() })` is being called every second updating the Clock with the current time. To my knowledge, `setState` calls the render method on the App which causes the whole component to be rerendered including the Label.

Is there a way pass date to Clock (causing it to be rerendered) without rerendering the entirety of the App component? How big of a role does this play in regards to performance?

Comment: Give the Clock component its own internal state rather than passing it as a prop of the parent.

Comment: First thing it's not recommended to do setState in either setTimeout or setInterval

Comment: There is a difference between the render function being called and the DOM actually being changed. The whole point of react is it renders into its virtual DOM then compares that with what it had before and only updates what is needed. This is called reconciliation. In your example Label would not be rerendered as it did not change, but Clock will be.

Comment: No, by default if parent rerenders all the children rerenders. @ChrisCousins probably you want to tell DOM manipulation is not needed in the Clock component.

Comment: There is a componentlifecycle method `shouldcomponentupdate` in case you wish to stop re-rendering for particular component

Comment: The Label element in the DOM will not be modified - it will have its virtual DOM rendered, but in the real DOM it will not be changed.

Comment: Yes DOM does not change but component itself rerenders.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not possible what you want. To pass a prop to a child component, the parent component's state or props should change somehow. As you know, this triggers a re-render obviously, so all the children re-render. To be updated, your `Clock` component should be re-rendered and unmounted/remounted in this situation to reflect the DOM change.

If your app is not so big and doesn't have so many children do not struggle with this problem since rendering is not so expensive. The expensive one is DOM manipulation of a component. Here, React diffs the real and virtual DOM and do not unmount/remount `Label` component even it re-renders. But, if you write your `Label` component as a `PureComponent` it doesn't re-render. But for `Clock` component to be updated like this, there is no way.

```
class Label extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    console.log("rendered");
    return (<p>{this.props.text}</p>)
  }
}

const Clock = ({ date }) => (
  <div>{date.toLocaleTimeString()}</div>
)

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      date: new Date()
    }
  }


  componentWillMount() {
    this.interval = setInterval(
      () => this.setState({ date: new Date() }),
      1000
    )
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval)
  }

  updateTime() {

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Label text="The current time is:" />
        <Clock date={this.state.date} />
      </div>
    )
  }

}
```

Comment: Is there any way to avoid propagation through the parents? I've highly nested structure (SVG), where I know that only certain children would be affected due to the changes in state.Currently I can see visible delay due to drill-down.

Comment: @NikunjMadhogaria, if I understand you right you are looking for `React.PureComponent`

Comment: Just tried quickly replacing Component to PureComponent, the functionality stopped working. I have only one single component that gets recursively called. My state has all the details about the children (an their children) including tags, attributes, etc. We wanted to see if you would gain on performance and code maintainability when switching to React. However, it appears to be slower than plain HTML (which has all the CSS rules for different variables) due to this recursion.

Comment: We have plain CSS rules like this `body[x="1"] #id1 = {...style 1}, body[x="2"] #id1 = {...style 2}`. This is currently faster than the recursion approach in React.

Comment: I can't say anything exactly but if you want to convert the code to React probably you should do it for all. Like DOM and CSS manipulations, etc.

Comment: Yes, I did that. Seems like React might not be the best solution when you have a very large and complex DOM tree. Pure CSS solution beats React. Thanks for the suggestions! :)

Comment: If it is done right there shouldn't be so much difference :) I'm pretty sure that there are lots of apps has a complex DOM tree in the wild and they use React :) But of course, choosing something depends on your needs.

Comment: Performance is one of the important metrics for our application. We had two solutions: first one was pure CSS, without any kind of javascript, second one was using React. If pure CSS was taking 200ms for an update, React was taking 2000ms for the same update (since it has an additional computation in javascript).

Comment: To anyone reading this thread, I was able to reduce unnecessary calls to `render()` method using one of the component life-cycle hooks `shouldComponentUpdate()`. This has improved the performance significantly! :D

Comment: You shouldn't be still using that paradigm.  Switch to hooks and use "memo".

Answer (score 21):

When you want to update a child without updating the parent, the state must be in the child. You can pass the state getter / setter from the child to the parent to be able to read and update it:

```
function Child({onMount}) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    onMount([value, setValue]);
  }, [onMount, value]);


  return (
    <div>
      {value}
    </div>    
  );
};


function Parent() {

  let value = null;
  let setValue = null;
  
  const onChildMount = (dataFromChild) => {
    value = dataFromChild[0];
    setValue = dataFromChild[1];
  };

  // Call setValue to update child without updating parent

  return (
    <div>
      <Child onMount={onChildMount}/>
    </div>    
  );
};
```

Since `const [value, setValue] = useState(0);` is in the `Child`, only the child component will re render when updating the value. Additionally, since the `Parent` receives `value` and `setValue` at `onChildMount`, the parent can use them to update the child without re rendering the parent.

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. The only change I made is that it's not necessary to pass `value` to the parent so `onMount(setValue);`  is sufficient.

Comment: Is this good practice?

Answer (score 3):

With `useImperativeHandle` and `React.forwardRef`, you can return the state from Child to Parent as ref:

```js
function Parent() {
  const childRef = useRef(null);
  
  function printValue() {
    console.log(childRef.current.value);
  }

  function setValueToOne() {
    childRef.current.setValue(1);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Child ref={childRef} style={{ color: "red" }} />
    </div>
  );
}

const Child = forwardRef(function Child({ style }, ref), () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => {
    return {
      value,
      setValue,
    }   
  }, [value, setValue]);

  return <div style={style}>{value}</div>
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Using reference of child component it can achievable:

```
export const parentA = () => {
  let ref = useRef<View>(null);
  const updateChild () {
    ref.current.props.setNativeProps({style:{backgroundColor: 'gray',}})
  }
  return (
    <childA>
      <Text>Test</Text>
    </childA>
  );
};

export const childA = () => {
  return <View style={{backgroundColor: 'green',}}></View>;
};
```