# React: set State or set Prop without a Rerender

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, rendering, setstate

## Problem:

Currently, I have a `LoginForm` component that has an "on-success" handler function `handleOnSuccess`. This the then linked to the parent component with an `onTokenUpdate` property defined by a "token-update" handler function `handleUpdateToken`. The problem is that the `setState` in the `handleUpdateToken` function is forcing an undesired rerender.

## Desired Outcome:

What I ultimately need is to update the `LoginForm` component property `token` with the value obtained on success WITHOUT performing a rerender. Is this even possible? According to [React: Update Child Component Without Rerendering Parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52018025/react-update-child-component-without-rerendering-parent) it would seem it is not, however, no feasible alternative for my case was suggested. Im wondering if anyone had any suggested alternatives if this is not possible.

## Code

### `LoginForm.react.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Script from 'react-load-script';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';


class LoginForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            linkLoaded: false,
            initializeURL: 'https://cdn.plaid.com/link/v2/stable/link-initialize.js',
        };

        this.onScriptError = this.onScriptError.bind(this);
        this.onScriptLoaded = this.onScriptLoaded.bind(this);

        this.handleLinkOnLoad = this.handleLinkOnLoad.bind(this);

        this.handleOnExit = this.handleOnExit.bind(this);
        this.handleOnEvent = this.handleOnEvent.bind(this);
        this.handleOnSuccess = this.handleOnSuccess.bind(this);

        this.renderWindow = this.renderWindow.bind(this);
    }

    onScriptError() {
        console.error('There was an issue loading the link-initialize.js script');
    }

    onScriptLoaded() {
        window.linkHandler = window.Plaid.create({
            apiVersion: this.props.apiVersion,
            clientName: this.props.clientName,
            env: this.props.env,
            key: this.props.publicKey,
            onExit: this.handleOnExit,
            onLoad: this.handleLinkOnLoad,
            onEvent: this.handleOnEvent,
            onSuccess: this.handleOnSuccess,
            product: this.props.product,
            selectAccount: this.props.selectAccount,
            token: this.props.token,
            webhook: this.props.webhook,
        });

        console.log("Script loaded");
    }

    handleLinkOnLoad() {
        console.log("loaded");
        this.setState({ linkLoaded: true });
    }
    handleOnSuccess(token, metadata) {
        console.log(token);
        console.log(metadata);
        this.props.onTokenUpdate(token);
    }
    handleOnExit(error, metadata) {
        console.log('link: user exited');
        console.log(error, metadata);
    }
    handleOnLoad() {
        console.log('link: loaded');
    }
    handleOnEvent(eventname, metadata) {
        console.log('link: user event', eventname, metadata);
    }

    renderWindow() {
        const institution = this.props.institution || null;
        if (window.linkHandler) {
            window.linkHandler.open(institution);
        }
    }

    static exit(configurationObject) {
        if (window.linkHandler) {
            window.linkHandler.exit(configurationObject);
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id={this.props.id}>
                {this.renderWindow()}
                <Script
                    url={this.state.initializeURL}
                    onError={this.onScriptError}
                    onLoad={this.onScriptLoaded}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

LoginForm.defaultProps = {
    apiVersion: 'v2',
    env: 'sandbox',
    institution: null,
    selectAccount: false,
    style: {
        padding: '6px 4px',
        outline: 'none',
        background: '#FFFFFF',
        border: '2px solid #F1F1F1',
        borderRadius: '4px',
    },
};

LoginForm.propTypes = {
    // id
    id: PropTypes.string,

    // ApiVersion flag to use new version of Plaid API
    apiVersion: PropTypes.string,

    // Displayed once a user has successfully linked their account
    clientName: PropTypes.string.isRequired,

    // The Plaid API environment on which to create user accounts.
    // For development and testing, use tartan. For production, use production
    env: PropTypes.oneOf(['tartan', 'sandbox', 'development', 'production']).isRequired,

    // Open link to a specific institution, for a more custom solution
    institution: PropTypes.string,

    // The public_key associated with your account; available from
    // the Plaid dashboard (https://dashboard.plaid.com)
    publicKey: PropTypes.string.isRequired,

    // The Plaid products you wish to use, an array containing some of connect,
    // auth, identity, income, transactions, assets
    product: PropTypes.arrayOf(
        PropTypes.oneOf([
            // legacy product names
            'connect',
            'info',
            // normal product names
            'auth',
            'identity',
            'income',
            'transactions',
            'assets',
        ])
    ).isRequired,

    // Specify an existing user's public token to launch Link in update mode.
    // This will cause Link to open directly to the authentication step for
    // that user's institution.
    token: PropTypes.string,
    access_token: PropTypes.string,

    // Set to true to launch Link with the 'Select Account' pane enabled.
    // Allows users to select an individual account once they've authenticated
    selectAccount: PropTypes.bool,

    // Specify a webhook to associate with a user.
    webhook: PropTypes.string,

    // A function that is called when a user has successfully onboarded their
    // account. The function should expect two arguments, the public_key and a
    // metadata object
    onSuccess: PropTypes.func,

    // A function that is called when a user has specifically exited Link flow
    onExit: PropTypes.func,

    // A function that is called when the Link module has finished loading.
    // Calls to plaidLinkHandler.open() prior to the onLoad callback will be
    // delayed until the module is fully loaded.
    onLoad: PropTypes.func,

    // A function that is called during a user's flow in Link.
    // See
    onEvent: PropTypes.func,


    onTokenUpdate: PropTypes.func,

    // Button Styles as an Object
    style: PropTypes.object,

    // Button Class names as a String
    className: PropTypes.string,
};

export default LoginForm;
```

### `App.js`:

```
// /* eslint no-magic-numbers: 0 */
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { LoginForm } from '../lib';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            access_token: null
        };
        this.handleUpdateToken = this.handleUpdateToken.bind(this)
    }

    handleUpdateToken(access_token) {
        this.setState({ access_token: access_token });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <LoginForm
                id="Test"
                clientName="Plaid Client"
                env="sandbox"
                product={['auth', 'transactions']}
                publicKey="7a3daf1db208b7d1fe65850572eeb1"
                className="some-class-name"
                apiVersion="v2"
                onTokenUpdate={this.handleUpdateToken}
                token={this.state.access_token}
            >
            </LoginForm>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Thanks in advance for any/all help!

Comment: you can use the token in `state` of `<LoginForm/>`

Comment: How do you mean? For this purpose, the token value must be assigned to a `property` of `LoginForm`, not a state - is this what you meant?

Comment: Do you need `access_token` to be  in `App`. From your example your not doing anything with it except pass it to `LoginForm`

Comment: @Sterling Butters Do you want to make some changes in `access_token` in the `<App />`?

Comment: @MohamedRamrami Yes it does have to be in `App` in order to build the Dash component correctly

Comment: @MaheerAli I'm afraid I'm still not sure what you mean. The `state` of `access_token` is "changed" by the `handleUpdateToken` function. What I need to "change" is the `property` `token` of `LoginForm` to the `state` of `access_token` __without__ a rerender.

Comment: @SterlingButters You want to update `access_token`(which will be passed my App) of your for LoginForm without calling the `render()` of the `<App/>` Am I right?

Comment: @SterlingButters I have tried to figure out a solution.I just used `token` instead of `access_token` in my post. Check it out

Comment: @MaheerAli Yes that's correct! But just to clarify I don't want to rerender __ONLY__ when the `access_token` is updated otherwise I do (obviously or nothing would happen). This also begs the question - if `<App/>` is not rerendered will the `token` `property` __actually__ be updated? I.e. if I was to request the value of the `token` `property` what would I get? (This is very important for Dash)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188155/discussion-between-maheer-ali-and-sterling-butters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot prevent rendering of `parent` if you want to update the `props` of child. But there is a way to achieve it.

1. You need to store the `token` in side your `LoginForm` state.
2. You need to change change the `state` of the `LoginForm` in `componentWillReceiveProps`
3. You need to pass a `token` and `function` in `this.props.onTokenUpdate(token,function);`.This function will have an argument which is token from parent. And inside `function` you will change the `state`.(This is needed if you want to alter the token in parent component and send updated one).
4. The `token` in parent shouldn't be in the `state` if you want to prevent `render()`. It should be compoent property
5. Use `this.state.token`Instead of `this.props.token`

Below is a general example.
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/maheer-ali/pen/XOZvBw?editors=1111)

Comment: Responded in chat

Comment: Have you had a chance to look at my specific case? I gave some more specific details in the chat

Comment: @Sterling Butters i have seen that. Buddy actually I can't because from next day my exams are comming. Please check codepen. Its so easy

Comment: Haha it probably is for you. Well, good luck on your exams thank you for your help! Maybe if I haven't figured it out by the time you are done with your exams I'll reach out again

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing (but I accepted @MaheerAli answer since some people may have been looking for that instead):

## `LoginForm.js`:

```
class LoginForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            linkLoaded: false,
            initializeURL: 'https://cdn.plaid.com/link/v2/stable/link-initialize.js',
        };

        this.onScriptError = this.onScriptError.bind(this);
        this.onScriptLoaded = this.onScriptLoaded.bind(this);

        this.handleLinkOnLoad = this.handleLinkOnLoad.bind(this);

        this.handleOnExit = this.handleOnExit.bind(this);
        this.handleOnEvent = this.handleOnEvent.bind(this);
        this.handleOnSuccess = this.handleOnSuccess.bind(this);

        this.renderWindow = this.renderWindow.bind(this);
    }

    onScriptError() {
        console.error('There was an issue loading the link-initialize.js script');
    }

    onScriptLoaded() {
        window.linkHandler = window.Plaid.create({
            apiVersion: this.props.apiVersion,
            clientName: this.props.clientName,
            env: this.props.env,
            key: this.props.publicKey,
            onExit: this.handleOnExit,
            onLoad: this.handleLinkOnLoad,
            onEvent: this.handleOnEvent,
            onSuccess: this.handleOnSuccess,
            product: this.props.product,
            selectAccount: this.props.selectAccount,
            token: this.props.token,
            webhook: this.props.webhook,
        });
    }

    handleLinkOnLoad() {
        console.log("loaded");
        this.setState({ linkLoaded: true });
    }
    handleOnSuccess(token, metadata) {
        console.log(token);
        console.log(metadata);
        this.props.onTokenUpdate(token);
    }
    handleOnExit(error, metadata) {
        console.log('PlaidLink: user exited');
        console.log(error, metadata);
    }
    handleOnLoad() {
        console.log('PlaidLink: loaded');
    }
    handleOnEvent(eventname, metadata) {
        console.log('PlaidLink: user event', eventname, metadata);
    }

    renderWindow() {
        const institution = this.props.institution || null;
        if (window.linkHandler) {
            window.linkHandler.open(institution);
        }
    }

    chooseRender() {
        if (this.props.access_token === null) {
            this.renderWindow()
        }
    }

    static exit(configurationObject) {
        if (window.linkHandler) {
            window.linkHandler.exit(configurationObject);
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id={this.props.id}
                 access_token={this.props.access_token}>
                {this.chooseRender()}
                <Script
                    url={this.state.initializeURL}
                    onError={this.onScriptError}
                    onLoad={this.onScriptLoaded}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

## `App.js`:

```
// /* eslint no-magic-numbers: 0 */
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { LoginForm } from '../lib';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            access_token: null
        };
        this.handleUpdateToken = this.handleUpdateToken.bind(this)
    }

    handleUpdateToken(access_token) {
        this.setState({ access_token: access_token });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <LoginForm
                id="Test"
                access_token={this.state.access_token}

                clientName="Plaid Client"
                env="sandbox"
                product={['auth', 'transactions']}
                publicKey="7a3daf1db208b7d1fe65850572eeb1"
                className="some-class-name"
                apiVersion="v2"
                onTokenUpdate={this.handleUpdateToken}
            >
            </LoginForm>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Most notably, I just defined a `chooseRender` function which chose whether or not to render Plaid in the Child.